# Get all checkins of venue

Tags: foursquare, swarm

I'm trying to develop a web application to show current checkins to the venue owner. Wenue owner will login to application and see his recent checkins. Who and when checked in.

I have tried venues/herenow (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow) but this call gives only checkins of friends and friends of friends.

Is there a way to get all recent checkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible if you want to check your own venue. Here is the API call :
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=simulate/venues/4e0deab3922e6f94b1410af3/stats